# App on Play store. Changed package name in Java. What part of Manifest needs old package name?

Tags: android, android-studio

I released an app on Play store a few years ago.

The package name was com.X.Y.appName

This week, I found the old source code and got it all working in Android Studio 14.

I did not like the package name for my Java code to be com.X.Y.appName

So, I changed the Java code to com.Z.appName

The Java code was fine with that, and everything runs fine in the emulator testing.

However, I now want to release the new version in the Play store.

So, how do I release this new project that is recoded as package com.Z.appName to be released as an update to com.X.Y.appName ?

The manifest.xml file references the package twice

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Z.appName">
```

and

```
<activity android:name="com.Z.appName.MainActivity">
```

Which of these needs to remain in the original package name to keep this App release to be considered an update, and not a brand new app ?

I tried to revert the first package name under the manifest tag back to com.X.Y.appName, and my code would no longer compile.  I am now getting "error: package R does not exist".  So, I put it back to com.Z.appName.

If I change the 2nd one in the activity tag, the code turns red, and I get "Class not found" error.

So, how do I release this new project that is recoded as package com.Z.appName to be released as an update to com.X.Y.appName ?

Do I leave the 2 entries above in manifest.XML to retain the new package name of com.Z.appName, but revert to the original com.X.Y.appName somewhere else entirely?

Build. Gradle?

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a way.  Does this seem correct?

I changed the manifest to the original package name

```
      <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.X.Y.appName">
```

Then I added this in MainActivity.java

```
 import com.X.Y.appName.R;
```

The project now compiles and works, and the manifest has the old project name.

Do I need to edit build.gradle as well ?
Currently, it shows the new package name

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.Z.appName"
```

Comment: one thing is change the package name, that you have done, you miss somewhere the new name so you can include R without an absolute path. Other thing is  upgrading the app in play store under a new package name. AFAIR that is not possible and you have to create a new application for that.